# Any risk of a SQL injection attack without parameters but it is enforced that the user input is restricted to the regex [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, sql-injection

I am using Entity Framework with PostgreSQL. I need to write a query that follows this format:

```
await Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("ALTER TABLE " + tableName + " ADD " + columnName + " " + sqlType);
```

As you can see, unfortunately I need to use user input for the table name, column name and the type of that column. And unfortunately, PostgreSQL doesn't support parameters for these types of input (like SQL Server does, for instance). So I don't really have an option here except to do string concatenation like so. I can, however, guarantee that both `tableName` and `columnName` will be constructed with the regex:

[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*

In other words I enforce that they will just be made up of just lowercase letters, uppercase letters and numbers. No punctuation or other special characters. As for `sqlType`, I can guarantee that this will be a string of the PostgreSQL type corresponding to the type for that column (e.g. `"int4"`, `"numeric"`, `"uuid"`, etc). It will definitely not be anything else because I use a dictionary to map between .NET types and these types in string format.

So does anyone know if this is still at risk of SQL injection attacks? Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Without punctuation I guess there would be no way to terminate the statement and issue a new, or comment out code following the injected statement, so I think you should be safe from injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be safe with that regex (as it doesn't include any Unicode chars & punctuation).